# unbinding the event using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing problem while unbinding the event using JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').unbind("click");
});
```

Its Not Working..

```
<td class="tddat matrixCellHt" align="center" onclick='javascript:DoHighlighting("tdMinPriceOnNonStop",<%#Container.ItemIndex%>);FilterResults("SingleAirlineParticularStop","0&<%#((string)DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "AirlineDisplayName"))%>")'  id="tdMinPriceOnNonStop<%# Container.ItemIndex %>"
```

Comment: Where is the event bound? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Are you sure that $('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0') is the correct id?

Comment: you can just change the onClick attribute if you don't find other solution:

$('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').attr("onclick","");

Answer (score 1):

It's not obligatory, but you should provide the handler you wish to unbind:

```
function doStuff(){
   //doing stuff
}

$('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').bind("click",doStuff);

//then
$('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').unbind("click",doStuff);
```

Comment: You're right, just read it in docu. I'll update my answer. Thx

Comment: I cant do it in that way because need sum server side value inside the repeater...So i need to only  unbind...  Please see the example above..

Answer (score 1):

go for

```
$('#tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').removeProp("onclick").removeAttr("onclick");
```

Because the event handler is stored directly in the element's property rather than in jQuery's $.data object (where jQuery stores all its handlers) you can't use jQuery's unbind method (removeProp removes the compiled handler. removeAttr isn't strictly necessary, but it removes the actual attribute (the string "javascript: ... ") too for greater consistency.

Answer (score 0):

you can `unbind()` handlers you only previously attached with `bind()`
(with jQuery 1.7+ you should use respectively `off()` and `on()`

If this is not the scenario just simply destroy any click handler defined for that element in plain javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   document.getElementById('tdMinPriceOnNonStop0').click = function() { };
});
```